# Method changes value of argument

Tags: java, matrix, methods, artificial-intelligence, puzzle

The method(Mover) belongs to a Estado Class, wich describes the state of a sliding puzzle with a matrix tablero(board) and a variable hueco(hole) that keeps track of the empty position. The problem is the function changes the value of the original Estado, and it is no supposed to. Can somebody tell me what did I make wrong please?

```
public class Estado {
public int dim;
public int tablero[][];
public int hueco[]= new int[2];
public Estado(int dim,int tablero[][],hueco){
    this.dim=dim;
    this.tablero=tablero;
    this.hueco=hueco;

}
public Estado(){}

//moves empty tile to one of 4 option(up,down,right,left)
(up,down,right,left)
//
public Estado mover(String direccion,Estado estado){
    Estado sig= new Estado();        
    sig.tablero=estado.tablero;
    sig.dim=estado.dim;
    sig.hueco=estado.hueco;
    estado.mostrarTablero();
    switch (direccion){
        case "up":                
            sig.tablero[estado.hueco[0]][estado.hueco[1]]=sig.tablero[estado.hueco[0]+1][estado.hueco[1]];
            sig.tablero[estado.hueco[0]+1][estado.hueco[1]]=0;
            sig.hueco[0]=estado.hueco[0]+1;
            break;               
        default:
//cases "down,right and left" omitted, very similar to "up"
            break;
    }               
    return sig;

}                                        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the variable `sig` points to the same arrays `tablero` and `hueco` of the argument `estado` because of this statements:

```
sig.tablero=estado.tablero;
sig.hueco=estado.hueco;
```

When you invoke `mover` method Java pass a copy of the "pointers" but not does a flat copy (copia plana) of the scrtucture of your arrays.

Maybe you prefer learn about topics *pass-by-value*, *pass-by-reference* and what it means make a *flat copy*.

Edit:
I take this from [Programmers StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/131626/185530) that should help you to understand:

> Java is pass by value. Think of it like a pointer language like C, the value of the pointer (memory address) is being passed, so you have a reference to the same object. Primitives aren't stored internally the same way as Objects, so when you pass a primitive's value, it's the content, not a pointer.

Comment: Thanks Guillermo, I got it now

Comment: For welcome! In stackoverflow you do not need to be grateful just accept the correct answers to clarify the solution for everyone else :)